# Get a contextual filter for a View in Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8

I'm converting a module from D7 to D8 for a client. Some of the code is working programmatically with views - something I haven't done that much in D7, since I just write my own queries.

In the code is this line:

```
$contextual_filter = method_exists($view, 'get_items') ? $view->get_items('argument', $display->id) : 0;
```

I need to convert this to D8, but I'm not sure entirely what I'm working with here.

What I do know:

- In D8, `$view` is an object of type `Drupal\views\ViewExecutable`
- In D8, there is no `get_items()` method, nor a `getItems()` method on ViewExecutable
- ViewExecutable has a property, `args`, and also a property `argument`

My questions:

1. How can I get the items from ViewExecutable
2. How can I get the contextual filter from ViewExecutable
3. Do I even need to do #1 to get #2?

Further down the code, I can see that $contextual filter is used as follows:

```
'contextual_filter' => !empty($contextual_filter) ? 1 : 0
```

So it would appear I'm just trying to get a boolean indicating whether or not a contextual filter exists.

Can anyone who has worked more with D7 Views more than I give me some insight as to what is happening with this code, and ideally how I can update it to D8? (Though insight as to what is happening in D7 may be enough for me to figure it out in D8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D8 the settings of a view are stored in a configuration entity. You can load the entity with View::load() or get it from the view executable directly and then load a display and check the contextual filters (stored in the key `arguments` of the display options):

```
$storage = $view->storage;
$display = &$storage->getDisplay('default');
$arguments = $display['display_options']['arguments'];

'contextual_filter' => !empty($arguments) ? 1 : 0
```